# Is it possible to rename a cordova plugin?

Tags: javascript, cordova, inappbrowser

I have cloned cordova InAppBrowser to my git. But I want to rename it something line foo so that the invoking methods change on my repo after installation using cordova cli

eg **cordova.InAppBrowser.open** > **cordova.foo.open**

I Think this file needs to be changed

[inappbrowser.js](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/www/inappbrowser.js)

Answer (score 1):

Edit the [plugin.xml](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/plugin.xml#L39) and change:

```
<clobbers target="cordova.InAppBrowser.open" />
```

to

```
<clobbers target="cordova.foo.open" />
```